# Limit size of the jSonArray in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jsonArray something like this.

```
var json_array = [
    { "text": "id", "size": 4}, 
    { "text": "manifesto", "size": 4}, 
    { "text": "also", "size": 4}, 
    { "text": "leasing", "size": 4},
    { "text": "23", "size": 4}, 
    ...
];
```

I want to get first n elements of this json_array.

What will be the best way to do it? Apart from iterating them and having a counter to limit the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short hand ([MDN Docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)):

```
json_array.length = n;
```

somewhat longer ([MDN Docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)):

```
json_array.splice( n );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var shorter_array = json_array.splice(0, N);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: plz remove the w3schools link. for details why see [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To copy your original array:

```
var newArray = json_array.slice(0, n);
```

Note this copy isn't recursive. That means if you change something in your an object in `newArray` it will also be changes in `json_array`.

---

Or as @Sirko says you can just remove elements from your array:

```
json_array.length = n;
```